# dexie.js: nested query very slow at first time

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

==========

update:

maybe this is not query make the indexeddb slow, but the save operation blocking the db. I get the data from webSocket, so almost 900 items need to save per second, and I save it one by one. Now I save it at memory, use 
 "bulkPut" function save all, almost 13 seconds done.

Apologize for my incomplete description, and thanks for all help!

==========

I try indexeddb first, but two nested transaction make the inner one very slow. Then I use Dexie.js, but things are same.

I refer to document，they says nested query are allowed, but all the example are single query.

In my case, there are two stores, one is named 'ps', and the other is named 'socket'. 'ps' objectStore has 4 items, but socket objectStore has maybe 10,000 items.

```
db.ps.toArray().then(lines => {
  lines.map(l => {
    console.log(l);
    console.time(l.name + '_' + 'sockets');
    db.socket.where('ps').equals(l.name).toArray().then(sockets => {
      console.timeEnd(l.name + '_' + 'sockets');

    })
  })
})
```

and here are the time log results:

67_sockets: 131583.873046875ms

42_sockets: 131614.40478515625ms

33_sockets: 131631.00805664062ms

22_sockets: 131634.97705078125ms

so where is the problem?  I think indexeddb is not so slow.

Comment: is there an index on the ps property in the socket object store?

Comment: indexDB.version(1).stores({
  socket: 'id,ps',
  ps: '&name',
  complateData: '&type'
});

Comment: is this a right format?

Comment: here I find a new trainThought : I got the data form webSocket, almost 900 items per second, and I save every item when I get it. So the whole indexeddb is blocked by the save operation, not transaction or other things. is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the whole function in a transaction block, otherwise each operation will launch in it's own transaction, which could show down the query.

```
let promise=db.transaction('r', db.ps, db.socket, ()=>
  db.ps.toArray().then(lines => {
    return lines.map(l => {
      console.time(l.name + '_' + 'sockets');
      return db.socket.where('ps').equals(l.name).toArray().then(sockets => {
        console.timeEnd(l.name + '_' + 'sockets');
        return sockets;
      })
    })
  }));
```

If still slow, check how large objects you are storing in the 'socket' object store. Or could it be a few of them containing huge amount of data?

Comment: I tried  encapsulate the code in a transaction block, and I just tried what you write, nothing change. a example of 'socket' objectStore is {"ps":67,"s":7043,"t":0,"dn":{"b":31.2,"h":4.25,"l":120.2},"id":89094,"up":{"b":31.5,"h":4.21,"l":120.6}}

Comment: Also remove the console.log() from every row (as I edited I'm my version) if that could occur a huge amount of time. Other than that, try inspect your data so that it does not include entries with huge amount of data.

Comment: According to your sample data, 131 seconds should not be the time it would take to retrieve 40,000 entries. I would expect around a few seconds only depending on cpu and memory.

Comment: thx for help, I find the query is not the reason, but the save operation, as I updated in question. Apologize for my incomplete description,  and thank you help me !

Comment: Ah, great and that explains it. By saving entries in a bulk you optimize a lot as it not only saves them all in one transaction but also does it faster than would be possible by calling Table.put() within a transaction. Your solution to use bulkPut() is the right one.